# Como criptografar um POST via Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, post

Como faço para criptografar os posts que envio via Ajax?
Por exemplo no Telegram Web eles fazem isso, dá pra ver pelo XHR com as requisições enviadas e recebidas.

Exemplo de como é no Telegram Web (desejo que minha aplicação também seja assim):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ps: estou desenvolvendo com Javascript e PHP.

Comment: pode usar funções como crypt() http://php.net/crypt

Comment: Essa request não está sendo feita sob `https` ?

Comment: Não sei. Queria um exemplo prático pra ver como funciona!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma maneira de fazer isso é utilizar a biblioteca jCryption (http://www.jcryption.org/).

Conforme o exemplo da página deles, o navegador mandaria a seguinte requisição.

```
POST

http://www.jcryption.org/jcryption.php?jCryption=U2FsdGVkX19Zw/DbJFLurww7uudVpt/sdgTx7ezKlLsxrx82sfFwdaZw7oT9a4Feu0EzKZ7w+yX7UC+R5K2wh/6Kwpt08yQ2K00yP+a2EnE=

HTTP/1.1
```

E no servidor chegaria os dados conforme esperado.

```
"email=john%40smith.com&password=1234&role=Admin&remember=on"
```

Comment: Valeu, cara isso vai me ajudar bastante.

Comment: Quanto a resposta do coléga "P. R. Ribeiro": Por ser uma biblioteca opensource, a criptografia não fica fácil de quebrar não?